# How can I avoid having an extra slash in the URL when doing a 301 redirect without hard-coding the destination?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I have a simple 301 redirect in my `.htaccess` file:

```
Redirect 301 /myfolder /
```

When somebody visits `example.com/myfolder`, they're redirected to `example.com//`

That works and doesn't appear to break anything, but it's ugly.

I know that I can hard-code the destination to fix it:

```
Redirect 301 /myfolder example.com
```

But that would add maintenance if the site moves to another domain.

Is there a way to redirect to the root (example.com) with no extra slashes and without specifying the domain?

Answer (score 0):

When using a 301 redirect is often recommended to use an absolute path, e.g.

```
redirect 301 /folder https://www.example.com/
```

or you cloud use a RewriteRule like this

```
RewriteRule ^/?folder/(.*)$ $1 [NE,R] [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```